# v-data-table: bind a custom property to "items" slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to create a table where every row represents an item. In the first column, I'm going to use a v-autocomplete component for choosing the item from a List of objects. Since the v-autocomplete is going to be inserted in the item template of v-data-table, I'm having problems binding a computed property to "v-bind:items" of v-autocomplete. The computed property is in the same file but it can't be found.

I tried to bind the computed property to the template with no result.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>
        <v-autocomplete
          :items="saleables"
          :item-text="i => i.name"
          :item-value="i => i.id"
          hide-details
        ></v-autocomplete>
      </td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
<template>


[...]
computed: {
  saleables: function () {
    return this.$store.getters['saleables/items']
  }
}
[...]
```

Comment: did you get errors?

Comment: As the code is I get a warning at runtime: `[Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]`

Comment: please share any warning or error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your template by `<v-app>` tag as follows:

```
  <template>
     <v-app>
      <v-data-table ...
        ...
      </v-data-table>
    </v-app>
 <template>
```

as mentioned in [`official docs`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/default-markup):

> In order for your application to work properly, you must wrap it in a v-app component. This component is required for determining grid breakpoints for the layout. This can exist anywhere inside the body, but must be the parent of ALL Vuetify components. v-content needs to be a direct descendant of v-app.